# I tried hosting an ASP.NET C# web application on *somee.com* and I am not able to display my homepage correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, somee

I am trying to host a web application on *somee.com* and I transferred over my application files and setup the database as well. I have a handful of pages in my file manager and one of them is *HomePage.aspx*, which is supposed to be my startup page when the website loads and I also added this in the *web.config* file:

```
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <add value="HomePage.aspx" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
```

But when I load the website, I get this page instead
[Wrong Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6I4a.png)

This page is what we get as *Default.aspx* when we first load the asp.net web application project. Let's say that my project name is *MyProject*. I posted the files inside *MyProject* excluding the *.vs, packages and .sln file* into the root folder at somee.com.
Is there anything else that I missed while setting up the files? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="HomePage.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you host your project on iis ? Did you restart your iis after changing config ?

Comment: It's hosted on the web hosting website somee.com. Do I need to stop and start my website on the web server for the changes to take effect?

Comment: It was good for troubleshooting if you could at least restart your application pool after config change.

Comment: It's a free plan and I thought that IIS would automatically detect a change in the web.config file. This is what they have as options: https://imgur.com/a/u3g9YtT

Comment: Changes to the web.config will trigger the app to be reloaded by IIS as soon as there are 0 connections left to the app. You have a shared host and you don't have full control of the webserver. Anyways this config is correct and should work if your path to homepage file is correct and there is no other redirection on your project or your webserver configs.

Comment: Check the path to your homepage file. With this path, Now it should be in the root directory with your web.config file.

Comment: The HomePage.aspx and the web.config are in the same root directory folder. Would you suggest a restart of the website based on the picture attached in the Imgur link?

Comment: Yes you can do it  for troubleshooting.